# Nulls not returning in Query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I have the following query that I want to exclude 'No' values for. I want to include N/A, Yes, and null. 'No', 'Yes', 'N/A', and 'null' are the only values in this column. When I run my query it does not return the null values but, it does return 'N/A' and 'Yes'.

---

```
select s.schoolid as "School Code", 
       sch.name as "School Name", 
       s.student_number as "Student Id", 
       s.lastfirst as "Name", 
       s.gender as "Gender", 
       s.grade_level as "Grade", 
       s.street as "Street", 
       s.city as "City", 
       s.state as "State", 
       s.zip as "Zip", 
       s.home_phone as "Home Phone" 
from u_students u 
  left join students s on u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
  left join schools sch on s.schoolid = sch.school_number
where s.grade_level in ('11','12')
  and s.enroll_status = '0'
  and U.Scs_Perm_Share_Military Not like 'No'
order by sch.name asc ;
```

Comment: Can you please paste here an example of how your tables look like and what's expected outcome from them?

Comment: Add this on the WHERE ... OR ISNULL assuming you are returning the column U.Scs_Perm_Share_Military with null values

Comment: Thanks all! This fixed the problem! Have a nice day!

Comment: Your `where` condition turns the outer join into an inner join. Move those conditions on the students table from the `where` to the `join` condition.

Comment: You misunderstand `outer join`, since it returns the rows of `inner join` plus others but your `where` must remove all the others (per the first sentence of a_horse_with_no_name's comment). Learn what it does. You don't explain what you want (so please edit your question per mrbox's comment) so we don't know whether the second sentence of a_horse_with_no_name's comment is what you need.)

Answer (score 0):

If a SELECT statement is to test for null values in addition to others, it must include an IS NULL clause.  Also as others have stated you should use left joined conditions instead of putting filter in the where clause:

```
select s.schoolid as "School Code", 
       sch.name as "School Name", 
       s.student_number as "Student Id", 
       s.lastfirst as "Name", 
       s.gender as "Gender", 
       s.grade_level as "Grade", 
       s.street as "Street", 
       s.city as "City", 
       s.state as "State", 
       s.zip as "Zip", 
       s.home_phone as "Home Phone" 
from u_students u 
  left join students s on u.studentsdcid = s.dcid
                      and s.grade_level in ('11','12')
                      and s.enroll_status = '0'
  left join schools sch on s.schoolid = sch.school_number
where (U.Scs_Perm_Share_Military IS NULL
       OR
       U.Scs_Perm_Share_Military <> 'No'
      )
order by sch.name asc ;
```

Comment: `U.Scs_Perm_Share_Military IS NULL OR` is unnecessary, since the `<> 'No'` is true for all values including NULL. Also assuming the `s.`s belong in a  `where` not an `on` means that using `left join` rather than `inner join` is poor practice.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270(v=sql.105).aspx   Look at the section titled, "comparing null values".

Comment: I see what you are saying, it's very possible he should put s.grade and s.enroll_status in the left join.

Comment: We *don't know* what they wanted, because the question is not clear. That is why an answer without a [mcve] should be commented on, close voted & downvoted--and not answered. Seems they just wanted inner joins--per their comment on the question saying `OR IS NULL` worked. Besides outer vs inner join the other thing I was saying was, again, you only need `<>'.